# PHP Not Responding after idle and databse connection

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

This problem is driving me mental, have spent many hours already on it.

We are developing a PHP based front-end for a MS SQL database, via a odbc connector.
We have ran in to a bug where if you open a page which connects to the database, and then leave it for about 2 minutes, and refresh the page. PHP Will timeout on the refresh. It will not timeout if you refresh within say 30 seconds. 
It will not do this if you are not connecting to the database.
`odbc_close` is called at the end of each page.

I have tried :

> ```
> 1.  The ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
> 2.  SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Driver/odbc connector  
> 3.  Installing and using the MSSQL method. Same result.
> 4.  Changing odbc_close to odbc_close_all on each page.
> 5.  Using apache 2.2
> ```

Running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008R2 with MSSQL Server 2005, PHP 5.4.15

Example Code Test db code :

```
for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
{
echo"$i <br>";
}

echo"<hr>";
//Sets Password/Username etc.
$conn = odbc_connect("JobTrackTesting","MyUserName","MyPassword");  

$Getsomething = odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT * FROM JobNumber");
while(odbc_fetch_row($Getsomething))
{
    echo odbc_result($Getsomething,JobNumber)."<br>";
}
echo odbc_errormsg();

odbc_close($conn);
```

Comment: just for fun try odbc_close_all(), only to test if problem is indeed called by un closed connection, try adding logs between connection open and close

Comment: other tip is to check TcpTimedWaitDelay ,http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx

Comment: check your my.cnf for a system variable called wait_timeout. If its not present add it to the section [mysqld] and restart your Mysql server.wait_timeout = 3600

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried the odbc_close_all, as stated in the original question.
I have also set the TcpTimedWaitDelay to 30 seconds previously, which didn't help.

How do you check the Time_Wait state in Windows Server?
The my.cnf doesn't apply to me as i am using a MS SQL server (microsoft sql server).

Any other ideas? got me pretty stumped!

Comment: I will try make a SQL server express on another computer and see if this removes the problem. Therefore it must be a problem with our SQL server.

Comment: Works with another SQL server. Must be related to our SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a conflict with OpenVPN, Routing the traffic through the wrong subnet.